# How to programatically determine server software in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to do small "server software check" to make sure that my PHP application is running on Apache.

I want to warn my users about security problems when they run my web application on Microsoft IIS servers.

I have some SSL-connection checks and they do not work under IIS, and I'm too lazy to write separate functions for IIS support.

---

**I need a function** that checks software, not "manual check" as @Eda190 suggested.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question above. The linked question above can be interpreted "How do I find out what server I'm running" (check the accepted answer for a clue to this). By my understanding, the asker is trying show a warning message programatically when the server the software is installed on doesn't match some criteria.

Comment: You are right @button, thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You are after:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apache_get_version` to get an apache version. If its not set its not apache.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php